# Como reduzir o espaçamento entre itens no BoxLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout

No meu exemplo, a classe `Teste` é um `JPanel` com `BorderLayout`.

Dentro da região central desse layout há um `JScrollPane` contendo outro `JPanel` com `BoxLayout` na vertical. A intenção é que os itens que eu adicionar a esse `JPanel` fiquem dispostos em lista na vertical.

Se você executar o exemplo e maximizar a janela eles fazem isso, mas ficam distribuídos igualmente dentro do `JPanel` e há espaços entre eles, que é o que não desejo. O que desejo é que eles ocupem somente o espaço necessário para caberem no layout e deixem uma sobra grande embaixo, como acontece se eu trocar as partes comentadas do código (trocar a adição dos `JPanelOrderRow` por `JLabels`).

Os itens que quero inserir na lista vertical (`JPanelOrderRow`) são `JPanels` com `GridBagLayout`.

Gostaria de entender por que isso está acontecendo e como faço para obter o efeito desejado.

Observação: Não posso usar `JList` no momento porque provocaria muito retrabalho na aplicação em que estou trabalhando.

**Teste.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Teste extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JPanel jPanelListaOrders = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane jScrollPaneOrders = new JScrollPane(jPanelListaOrders);

    public Teste() {

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(jScrollPaneOrders, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jPanelListaOrders.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(254, 254, 254));
        jPanelListaOrders.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(jPanelListaOrders, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        // Adicionando somente esses quatro JPanelOrderRow, eles ficam
        // espaçados por igual no layout, o que não quero.
        jPanelListaOrders.add(new JPanelOrderRow());
        jPanelListaOrders.add(new JPanelOrderRow());
        jPanelListaOrders.add(new JPanelOrderRow());
        jPanelListaOrders.add(new JPanelOrderRow());

        // Adicionando somente esses quatro JLabels, fica uma sobra embaixo
        // deles que é o que desejo.
        //jPanelListaOrders.add(new JLabel("Teste"));
        //jPanelListaOrders.add(new JLabel("Teste"));
        //jPanelListaOrders.add(new JLabel("Teste"));
        //jPanelListaOrders.add(new JLabel("Teste"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Teste");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new Teste());
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**JPanelOrderRow.java**

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

public class JPanelOrderRow extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JPanelOrderRow() {
        initComponents();
        initializeData();
    }

    private void initializeData() {
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(254, 254, 254));
        setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 1, 0, new java.awt.Color(237, 237, 237)));
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 128, 0 };
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 18, 0 };
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
        setLayout(gridBagLayout);
        lblName = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        lblName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        lblName.setText("Nome do cliente");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_lblName = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_lblName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        gbc_lblName.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_lblName.gridx = 0;
        gbc_lblName.gridy = 0;
        add(lblName, gbc_lblName);
    }
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblName;
}
```

[image: Espaçamento indesejado entre as linhas]

[image: Sem espaçamento e com uma sobra embaixo, que é o desejado]

Comment: Onde está o espaçamento?

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci de falar. Tem que maximizar a janela para ver.

Comment: A causa é a mesma que eu disse na outra pergunta, é devido ao seu layout, você está misturando um monte de layouts diferentes.

Comment: Estou misturando porque imagino que o Swing trabalha assim, com layouts diferentes mesmo. Tenho BoxLayout para compor uma lista de elementos e cada elemento tem um layout GridBagLayout. Qual é o problema nisso? O que eu deveria fazer no lugar?

Comment: O boxlayout vai sempre redimensionar tudo dentro dele pra ocupar o maior espaço possivel até que todos estejam distribuidos dentro da janela, nao adianta nada definir parametros de gridbaglayout no JPanel interno, porque o layout mais externo(boxlayout) é que vai definir a distribuição e isso não é alteravel, a nao ser que reescreva o layout manualmente.

Comment: O mesmo não ocorre no JLabel porque ele tem definições que, a não ser que você defina tamanhos manuais relativos ao tamanho da tela, ele irá sempre ocupar o tamanho necessário apenas para exibir seu proprio conteudo, é uma caracteristica do componente JLabel, e o layout não se sobrepoe a isso.

Comment: Entendi! Experimentei trocar o `JLabel` por um `JPanel` com `JLabel` dentro e deu o mesmo problema que o `GridBagLayout`. É culpa do `BoxLayout` então. Eu até tentei adicionar cola (_vertical glue_) pra ver se ajudava mas não mudou nada. O que fazer então? Tirando `JList` não conheço nenhum outro layout que me ajude no lugar de `BoxLayout` para produzir uma lista vertical.

Comment: Você precizará definir um tamanho maximo para o JPanel, o BoxLayout respeita os tamanhos dados para os componentes, quando não há nada informado, o tamanho maximo é `Interger_MAX_VALUE` para largura e altura.

Comment: Entendi. Vou tentar. Faz uma resposta aí que eu aceito!

Comment: Já achei uma solução, é bem boba, mas faz o embasamento que expliquei fazer sentido

Comment: Se não se encomodar, eu vou converter os comentários na resposta, pra não ter que explicar de novo e evitar a fadiga :p

Comment: Fique à vontade :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `BoxLayout` vai sempre redimensionar tudo dentro dele pra ocupar o maior espaço possível até o tamanho máximo definido por cada componente dentro dele. Por isso os parâmetros de gridbaglayout no `JPanel` interno não alteram o tamanho dos componentes.

O mesmo não ocorre no `JLabel` porque ele tem definições que, a não ser que você altere manualmente os tamanhos dele, irá sempre ocupar o tamanho necessário apenas para exibir seu próprio conteúdo, é uma característica deste componente, e o `BoxLayout` não se sobrepõe a isso, pois respeita os tamanhos definidos pelo próprio componente através dos métodos `setPreferredSize()`, `setMaximumSize()` e `setMinimumSize()`.

Você precisará definir um tamanho máximo para o `JPanel`, o `BoxLayout` respeita os tamanhos dados para os componentes, quando não há nada informado, o tamanho máximo é definido como `Interger_MAX_VALUE` para largura e altura, e enquanto houver espaço na janela, o layout tentará preencher cada componente o máximo possível até chegar no valor máximo definido por cada um.

A solução, retirada [desta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653369/5524514), parece até boba mas apenas explora esta característica do BoxLayout, definindo o tamanho máximo do JPanel para o tamanho preferido, que geralmente é o necessário para compor seu conteúdo, incluindo bordas e espaçamento interno. Apenas adicione a seguinte linha ao final do método que constrói o JPanel `JPanelOrderRow` e veja a mágica dos layouts acontecer:

```
setMaximumSize(getPreferredSize());
```

Resultado:

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>